# Ubuntu 22.04 search applications aren't clickable

Tags: 22.04, bug-reporting

Just updated to Ubuntu 22.04. Had a couple of issues, most of them I was able to resolve, except for this one. When performing a search in the activities menu for an application, I cannot click on the application when the search results come up. Initially, the first search result will be highlighted, if you use the arrow keys, nothing becomes highlighted and you cannot select the application. Otherwise, files and internal settings are all clickable.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to a shell theme I had called nordic. I updated the theme to nordic-40 and it corrected the issue.